# Permission denied to modify the 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder' folder

Tags: .net, .net-core

Please help me with .NET Core when I use

```
C:\Users\ALI>dotnet new console -o myApp 
C:\Users\ALI>cd myApp
C:\Users\ALI\myApp>dotnet run
```

In command prompt

I except the output to be

```
 "Hello World!"
```

because the code is that,
but I ran into an ERROR:

> Permission denied to modify the
>   'C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder' folder.

Comment: Run `dotnet restore` as administrator at least once, so that the SDK can fix itself.

Comment: @LexLi You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a known bug in dotnet core https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9807 and the fix *suggested* from https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9807#issuecomment-464336743 is to

> Same issue on Windows10 with .NET Core 2.2.104. I deleted the NuGetFallbackFolder then went to Windows Add/Remove Programs and clicked repair it. Well, it somehow is repaired. I checked the C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk and the NuGetFallbackFolder is back with no error on each run now.

I came across your question googling for the bug report, experiencing a similar problem on Linux.
I do hope the dotnet core team fixes this soon.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install GIT for Windows;

2) right-click it, open it as Run as Administrator;

3) re-run